# Does $\frac{1}{1-f(x)}$ have the same MacLaurin series expansion as $\frac{1}{1-x}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am seeking the Maclaurin series expansion for

$$\frac{1}{1-(x+1)}$$

I know that

$$\frac{1}{1-x} = 1+x+x^2 +\ldots$$

Can I replace $x$ with $x+1$?

More generally, can I replace $x$ with any function $f(x)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you may replace your $x$ with f(x) as long as the resulting infinite series stay convergent.
In your example of $$ \frac {1}{1-(x+1)}= 1+(x+1) + (x+1)^2 +....$$

You have to be careful that you need $$|x+1|<1$$ for the series to converge.

Answer (score 1):

No problem with replacement, but keep in mind that result will only converge for sure when $|f(x)|<1.$ [deleted incorrect statement about when $|f(x)|=1.$]